# IntelliJ - Multiple modules in 1 project

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

### Background

So I recently have migrated over to Intellij from heavy use of Eclipse. My goal is to make IntelliJ (currently v14 as of posting) my primary Java IDE. Now, I've been learning what I can over the past couple of days about IntelliJ and it's differences when compared to Eclipse so that I can move mindsets. Things like workspace -> project, and project -> module.

### Problem

I want to have multiple modules in a project and simply group them. I do not want multiple windows of IntelliJ open and have to work on multiple projects. I much prefer 1 project with many groupings of modules so that I can easily move between modules. This was working, I starting importing/creating modules and proceeded to add them to a grouping (I had to change the view thingy to another and back for it to update. This thing: http://i.imgur.com/rOlh31h.png?1). Odd, but okay, it was working. Then I was importing a module but some reason it popped up saying do I want to open a new project window, or replace the current project window, I clicked X because I wanted to cancel but it replaced my current project window. Now I've lost all the imported modules.

### Question

How can I make a project view persistent? This would be either a way to save a project and then load it later perhaps. It's becoming quite annoying losing all my groupings of modules.

Comment: sounds like a bug in idea, try to recover original project from your local history. and try again importing

Comment: There is no option to export or save a project. I see import a project, but I don't know where each project is saved so I can't use that. My files are still safe, but my view of them inside IntelliJ (them listed inside a project/module grouping) is gone.

Comment: right click on the project -> local history -> show history and you can go back to older version if project file is messed up. I'm pretty sure your view is gone because the project file got changed.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure my project stays? I only want one to work with a bunch of modules.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, when you import projects something must have gone wrong and it might have overwritten the file, that's what I can think of what you are saying.

Comment: Please see my answer, I've figured out what happened. Apologies for my mistake and thank you for helping me sort it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to overwrite the current project's window through importing modules (as far as I know). Although, when one were to accidentally import a project (thinking they were importing a module) it would surely overwrite the project window if when prompted they chose to open in current window.